# Arc length from a curved roof?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

I am asking for help to understand one problem I have been assigned. My English is not great so I would appreciate any help clarifying what is really being asked.

I have a 2D figure consisting on a box and an arc representing a warehouse, with the roof being the arc of a circumference (black part in the image). There is information on the width of the warehouse (45m) but not the height (could be parameterized?). Also there is information on the largest distance between the roof arc and the box (11.5m).

I am asked to calculate through algebraic operations the *smallest distance across the surface of the roof*. Please let me know if I am wrong, but I think this means the arc length of the roof (the red curved segment part):

[image]

If the arc length interpretation is correct, what would be a good way to compute it? I guess  I could compute the circumference that contains the roof arc and then compute the arc length from it

Best regards and many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The best way for a fluent English speaker to tell you what is being asked would be if you used the *exact words* of the original question, instead of paraphrasing it.

Comment: You need to find the radius of the circle that the arc (above the roof) *corresponds* to.  This radius, $~R,~$ must satisfy $~R^2 = (22.5)^2 + (R - 11.5)^2.~$  Having found the radius, you then need to determine the angle formed by the two line segments that each run from one of the upper corners of the roof to the center of the circle.  Then, once the radius and angle are known, the arc length is known.

Comment: The circular arc has three fixed points where it connects to the rectangle and the midpoint and any three non-colinear points define a unique circle. Try to find its center point then calculate the arclength using that and the endpoints.